# combining two data sources in a database

Tags: database-design

I have a question about best practices when combining two data sources which both have partial data and occasionally contradictory data.

I have two different data sources that I'm using to get variables related to specific houses (Zillow and Redfin).

There are discrepancies between the two data sources. For the same house, one of the data sources may be missing a particular variable, and so I collect that data from the other source. Sometimes both sources may have the variable, but the values differ for the same house, indicating that one of the sources must be wrong.

I'm not sure what best practices are for storing the data and ensuring that the final data set has the most coverage and is most likely to include the correct data.

Some of the ideas I am toying with are:

1) Store both in separate tables, and then combine in a third table which contains the statistics that I create from the underlying data. The problem with this approach is that I would need a substantially bigger database.

2) Insert one set of data, and then grab the same data from the other source, and overwrite in the same table wherever relevant. The problem with this approach is that if I want to go back and make changes to how I compute the statistics, I may not know which source I retrieved the data from.

Are there any best practices for combining different data sets?

I'm also not entirely sure how to make the choice between conflicting values of the same variable for the same house. Should I always stick with one of the sources?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: yep, just I was working in sql. removed the tags

Comment: I'd store each input on its own table, as is. Input sources may have to be loaded or reloaded in different times. Then I'd keep a third table with the result of the merge and data cleansing procedure. This procedure could be parametrized so as to give different outputs and manage conflicts in a different way. As for data coming in from different sources but with different values... you must decide which is more authorative, or weigh it or implement some choice algo... and this may very well have to be different for different columns of data.